# End my urls with trailing slash (/) or not? And how do I go about it doing this with codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out which is most appropriate.  From the articles I have read, it seems best to end url's with a trailing slash.

So instead of:
http://example.url/article

It would read:
http://example.url/article/

First I adjusted my htaccess to force a trailing slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^.+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$              $1/
```

Then I started implementing this in my links and I thought if I did anchor('article/','article') it would work, but it seems that this function strips the trailing slash.

To get around this I changed the config file to have $config['url_suffix'] = '/'.  Which worked *mostly* fine - except I have a document area on my site with pdf's and such. So the links created there would turn out like http://example.url/documents/doc1.pdf/ . This of course does not work.

What do you think my solution is here? I guess I could go back to any page I referenced documents or files in and adjust them to not use the anchor function, but I feel like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My sites use both. The trailing slash indicates something specific to users, i think. Since the "/" usually indicates a folder, users (especially technical) take this to mean that there are sub-folders or sub-parameters to this page. Not showing a user that slash could indicate that there are no sub folders. This works for things like files, such as your pdf file.

Because of this, I have chosen not to force either side, but to build my site in a way that reflects the users perceptions. But thats a philosophy thing, you build a site for users, not for the code, right? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to maybe be rude-ish, but if it doesn't work (or causes problems), just don't do it and you're fine. Adding extra code for that kind of thing is wasted time. Some browsers add the slash automatically, so why worry? It really does not matter.

Comment: i agree, its extra code, causing your system to be less reliable by forcing more specifications..for what? consistency? But only for your site, which people might confuse with other sites, which do it differently.

Comment: well i have read that search engines view "page/" and "page" differently.  So I want to have all my links be one way to optimize my site.

Comment: @Roeland I believe they view them different as I have stated how users view them in my answer. You can check with Google, they make it very clear that if you want to optimize then you need to build your site best for the user.

Comment: @Roeland ps, according to a random link in a google search, MSN and Y! automatically strip the trailing slash, and G indexes whichever is given. But they did state that technically no slash is considered a resource and a slash is considered a directory, which is basically a rephrase of what i stated.

Comment: makes sense.. interesting that its stripped automatically by some.

Answer (score 0):

Override `site_url()` from `Config.php` to add a trailing slash, except when linking to a file:

`application/core/MY_Config.php`:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Config extends CI_Config {

    function site_url($uri = '')
    {   
        if ($uri == '')
        {
            return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page');
        }

        if ($this->item('enable_query_strings') == FALSE)
        {
            $suffix = '';
            if( ! preg_match('/(.+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/', $uri))
            {
                $suffix = '/';              
            }
            return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->slash_item('index_page').$this->_uri_string($uri).$suffix;              
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->slash_item('base_url').$this->item('index_page').'?'.$this->_uri_string($uri);
        }
    }

}
// END MY_Config Class

/* End of file MY_Config.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Config.php */
```